# How to continue accessing 'Youtube Analytics API' with PHP Client library 'googleapis/google-api-php-client' after 31st October when V1 is depricated?

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I have been using googleapis/google-api-php-client v2.2.2 (latest) on github but it uses v1 of the Youtube Analytics API. On Oct 31 2018, the v1 api is depricated. Currently, a php method for v2 of Youtube analytics api doesn't appear to be available? What will the community be doing to continue access to the Youtube Analytics API? Perhaps move to the Python library?

Comment: finally the api is depricated but still not possible to migrate while using the php client library?<br/>
  "code": 410,
  "message": "Version 1 of the YouTube Analytics API has been deprecated as of November 1, 2018. Please refer to the migration guide for details about how to update your client to work with version 2 of the API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/migration."

Answer (score 1):

The google api php client library has now been updated to work with v2 of the Youtube Analytics API.
It has moved on github to here:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services

Beware: This is what caught me out: The latest version in the /releases folder is 2.2.2 which still uses the depricated v1 analytics API. https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases

Hope that helps.